# Как размещать svg в html

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation

я новичок изучаю веб своими силами и у меня вылезло несколько вопросов по поводу использования svg на странице html.

### 1. Как правильно вставлять svg в html?

Знаю несколько способов а какой будет правильный  что бы потом не было ни вопросов, ни проблем с той, же интерактивностью (анимацией если придется анимировать).
Знаю такие способы как:

1. Вставить svg инлайново(просто вставить весь код svg в html).
2. Если иконок больше одной, то отдельно и вставлять их в html где они используются.
3. Вставлять с помощью object, iframe, embed.
4. Собрать все иконки в спрайт и вытаскивать их с помощью use.

### 2. Где хранить спрайт?

В html или отдельным файлом спрайтом.
Умею вытаскивать иконки из спрайта, если он весь лежит в html или даже если он лежит отдельным файлом.svg где-нибудь в картинках. Уметь то умею но как делать это. А если быть точнее, то где хранить спрайт чтобы не было проблем с кэшированием или какие там проблемы еще бывают…

Можете привести примеры из реальных проектов, что бы было, на что опереться для дальнейшего развития.

### 3. Использовать внешние стили или писать их внутри svg?

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [С помощью какого тега лучше всего добавлять svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112714/%d0%a1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-svg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Знаю несколько способов а какой будет правильный что бы потом не было
> ни вопросов, ни проблем с той, же интерактивностью (анимацией если
> придется анимировать).

### #1. object

Лучший способ, чтобы реализовать анимацию, интерактивность, стилизацию, масштабирование это:
`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg" width="200" height="200" ></object>`

Этим способом можно добавлять как один файл SVG, так и несколько иконок, объединенных в спрайт. Этой теме посвящен раздел с меткой - [svg-спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

Вот лучшее, на мой взгляд, [руководство по созданию спрайтов](http://dreamhelg.ru/2017/02/symbol-svg-sprite-detail-guide/)

### #2. Инлайн добавление кода SVG в HTML

Если иконок немного и код svg компактный, то вполне допустим этот способ для реализации анимации и всего остального:

*Ниже код анимации шестеренок с кнопками пуска и остановки вращения.*

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
       >
  
    <defs>
        <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5"
            markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
            markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
            <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
        </marker>
        <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100"
            style=" fill:none;
             marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
             marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
           stroke:grey; stroke-width:6; ">
      
        </line> 
        <marker id="MarkerArrow2" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="3.5"
            markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  orient="auto"
            markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
            <rect width="7" height="7" rx="2" fill="grey"/>
        </marker>
        <line id="line2" x1="168.5" y1="100" x2="211.5" y2="100"
            style=" fill:none;
             marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow2);
             marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow2);
             stroke:grey; stroke-width:3.5; ">
      
        </line> 
        
     </defs>
<g id="coleso">
     <g>
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="rotate"
                        from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100"
                         begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="7s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
          />
     <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(0 100 100)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(120 100 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line1"  transform="rotate(240 100 100)"/>
   
       <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
    </g>
</g>

<g id="coleso2" transform="rotate(20 100 100)">
     <g>
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="rotate"
                        from="0 190 100" to="-360 190 100"
                         begin="gO1.click" end="stop1.click" dur="7s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"
          />
     <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(0 190 100)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(120 190 100)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#line2"  transform="rotate(240 190 100)"/>
   
       <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="7.5"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 3px;" />
      <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="25"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none;   stroke-width: 6px;" />
     <circle cx="190" cy="100" r="30"  style="stroke: grey; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 5px;" />
    </g>
</g>
<g transform = "translate(30,50)">
  <g id="gO1">
   <rect x="35" y="165" height="20" width="60" rx="5" fill="green"/>
   <text x="50" y="181" font-size="18" fill="white">GO</text>
  </g>
 <g id="stop1">
    <rect x="100" y="165" height="20" width="60" rx="5" fill="red"/>
    <text x="105" y="181" font-size="18" fill="white">STOP</text>
 </g>
</g>  
    </svg>
```

### #3.  Использование `<iframe>` тега.

`<iframe src="SvgImg.svg"></iframe>`
Так как браузеры могут отрисовывать по своим правилам SVG документы, то это дает возможность загружать картинки внутри тегов `<iframe>`.

> Это может быть хорошим методом, если вы хотите полностью отделить SVG
> код и скрипт на вашей главной странице. Однако манипуляции SVG
> изображениями с главной страницы при помощи JavaScript будут немного
> сложнее.

### #4. Другие способы добавления SVG, которые делают анимацию, стилизацию невозможной

`<img src="image.svg" width="200" height="200" alt="image description">`

Можно, как обычно для любого другого изображения задать ширину, высоту.

По соображениям безопасности при этом способе добавления SVG браузеры отключают скрипты, связывания и другие типы интерактивности, когда они добавляются на страницу, кроме того `IE10`,`Edge`, `Safari`, `Chrome` не принимают стили, если они определены в отдельном файле таблицы стилей.

Для покраски изображений остается только один способ: фильтры SVG и CSS

Ниже примеры изменения цвета при наведении:

```html
<style>
img:not(:hover) {
  transition: 2s;
  filter: saturate(0%);
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
  }
img:hover {
  transition: 1s;
}
</style>
<img width=200 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg">
```

```html
<style>
.img:hover{
filter: invert(12%) sepia(83%) saturate(5841%) hue-rotate(244deg) brightness(87%) contrast(153%);
 -webkit-filter: invert(12%) sepia(83%) saturate(5841%) hue-rotate(244deg) brightness(87%) contrast(153%);
}
</style>
<img class="img"  src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/beacon.svg" width="300" height="300" >
```

О других способах добавления SVG в HTML [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

Answer (score 3):

Как правильно, мне сказать сложно. Поэтому скажу как делаю я ).

Делаю несколько спрайтов, объединяя по какой-нибудь своей логике, и скидываю в `/images/icons/`.
Подключаю через `use`.

Вроде как это один способов, который позволяет кэширование.
Также позволяет использовать указание некоторых svg-параметров через css.